# SchemaRDD (Hive Table Scan) not cached by Spark-Shell

Tags: caching, hive, apache-spark

I'm trying to run some basic data exploration using Spark on a Hive table (hosted on CFS via DataStax 4.6). My dataset is about 3.1GO and I run the spark-shell with dse spark --executor-memory 16g (Yes I do have 16g available on my executors). So basically I would write into the spark-shell, the following:

```
val dataset = hc.sql("SELECT * FROM my_hive_table") ;
val data_sample = dataset.sample(false,.01,0) ;
data_sample.cache
```

and then I would try a count to actually cache something

```
data_sample.count
```

but when I check on the spark-shell web UI I see no RDD persisted and if I try a count again my whole dataset is read again from CFS.

So I tried accessing my dataset though CFS directly as a textfile as such

```
textFile.type = cfs:/user/hive/warehouse/my_hive_table/aaaammjj=20150526
```

and adapt the previous code to count the number of line after caching the RDD and this time the RDD is indeed cached using 7 GB across two workers ! From the web UI :

> cfs:/user/hive/warehouse/my_hive_table/aaaammjj=20150526  Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated

Is there any reason why my schemaRDD is not cached using Hive ? That would be much pratical since schemaRDD provide ... well the schema.

Thx for any help.

Comment: set a name for your cache and check the UI again!

Comment: Do you mean something like `val rdd_in_cache = data_sample.cache` ? I tried this also with no success.

Comment: I mean data_sample.cache.setName("Data Sample")

Comment: No success either ... with `.cache` and then `.cache.setName("")` or `.cache.setName("")` alone.

Comment: please add a screenshot of your Spark Web UI storage tab!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upload picture to Stackoverflow due to low reputation. Anyway the web UI window displaying the RDD (storage tab) is basically empty. This happens only this SchemaRDD. I could cache a textfile or a simple Parallelized Collections with no problem (and the RDD is then displayed in that window with a number as a name or the file path from CFS).

Comment: I've answered your question down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on my discussion with eliasah, I could eventually cache the table somehow with :

```
val dataset = hc.sql("SELECT * FROM autori_daily_import")
dataset.registerTempTable("data")
hc.cacheTable("data")
hc.sql("select count(*) from data")
res22: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([6409331])
hc.sql("select sens,count(*) from data group by sens").collect().foreach(println)
[A,3672249]
[E,2737082]
```

And there is indeed a RDD in cache with name "RDD Storage Info for HiveTableScan ..."

What is a litle fuzzy to me is why I need to register a temporary table when I have a schemaRDD for which I have a .cache() method. If I run queries against the schemaRDD (with .select('sens).countByValue() ) then Spark scan the Hive table again and don't use the temporary in-memory table.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html) of Spark 1.2, Spark SQL can cache tables using an in-memory columnar format by calling sqlContext.cacheTable("tableName").

Then Spark SQL will scan only required columns and will automatically tune compression to minimize memory usage and GC pressure. You can call sqlContext.uncacheTable("tableName") to remove the table from memory.

Note that if you call `schemaRDD.cache()` rather than `sqlContext.cacheTable(...)`, tables will not be cached using the in-memory columnar format, and therefore `sqlContext.cacheTable(...)` is strongly recommended for this use case.

Configuration of in-memory caching can be done using the setConf method on SQLContext or by running SET key=value commands using SQL.

So actually you'll need to cache your data_sample RDD using `sqlContext.cacheTable("the name of the table you gave for your table")`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the table concept in Spark. What do I need to add once I have my SchemaRDD ready ? (rdd.registerTempTable("tbl") ?) And also if I look at the API documentation regarding schemaRDD (same version) I can read [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD) regarding the cache() method : "Overridden cache function will always use the in-memory columnar caching." So I'm not sure I need to go though a table declaration somehow. Thx for you help.

Comment: Well first, if you want to work with SchemaRDDs you have to get familiar with tables, like the one you used with `my_hive_table`. Secondly, you don't need to understands under the hood concerning the caching method used by Spark to accomplish what you are trying to do! You just need to follow what I wrote in my answer

Comment: Well actually I read that and so I've also tried this : `data_sample.registerTempTable("sample")` and `sqlContext.cacheTable("sample")` but I got the following error : "java.lang.RuntimeException: Table Not Found: sample" but since I'm not very familiar with this concept and since I could query my schemaRDD with method like .select or .where (and since my schema is known by hive) I didn't see any point in the table concept.

Comment: Follow [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) example to understand how you can create a table with hive tables!

Comment: Well this is exactly what I did when using this command : `val dataset = hc.sql("SELECT * FROM my_hive_table")` hc is the HiveContext. The table was already existing in Hive.

Comment: yes but dataset is Dataframe and not a SchemaRDD. I'm trying to check if there is a known issue about that

Comment: Are you sure about this : "scala> dataset
res12: org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD =
Data Set SchemaRDD[0] at RDD at SchemaRDD.scala:103" This says SchemaRDD not DataFrame ?? Also DataFrame comes with Spark 1.3 and I'm using 1.1.0

Comment: try `data_sample.registerAsTable("sample")` instead of `data_sample.registerTempTable("sample")`